# Cannot upgrade released managed package to beta because it is referenced by an extension package

Tags: managed-package, unmanaged-package, beta-managed-package

We are trying to upgrade a released managed package to the next beta. I know this is possible as I have done it before. However, this time we are getting this error. Can anyone shed any light? What is an extension package? Many thanks.

Package name cannot be upgraded using a managed-beta version of this package because it is referenced by an extension package developed in this organization.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the problem was an Unmanaged package that referenced our Managed Package. As a solution, we deleted the Unmanaged package (which left its components in tact).

Comment: just wondering how come it "left its components intact"? If you try to uninstall even an unmanaged package, Salesforce removes its components. What did you do to avoid the latter?

Comment: It wasn't an installed unmanaged package. It was deployed using the Force.com Migration Tool. So appeared in Package Manager instead of Installed Packages. In that case the package is just a shell for its components.

Answer (score 0):

As the error already mention that there is a depended package which exist in your org and that will not allow you to upgrade it to beta.

Because beta package can't be updated again and thats why it is not allowing you to upgrade it to beta.

So first remove or uninstall the dependent package and then update this package.

The only way to uninstall a Beta Package is to completely uninstall the managed package that the beta is a version of.  This means that if a customer is developing on top of the managed packages with their own custom objects, triggers, etc. that references objects within the package uninstalling is a pain of needing to go through and delete all of their custom development work, uninstall the beta managed package, reinstall the released managed package, then re-deploy all of their custom development work, then redeploy (or recreate) their data.

Also from the standard SF doc `Packages cannot be upgraded to Managed - Beta if they are used within the same organization as an extension.`

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=publish_extensions.htm&language=en)

Comment: Downvote without comments. Thanks for leaving me blank.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. I said that I'd already installed a managed released version, not a beta.

Comment: @fred Did you check your own answer? You said you have dependent unmanaged package.you removed that to solve this. Now read my first 3 para I said same. Now what else did you expect from my side?

Comment: Your answer related to upgrading a beta to another beta, which is not the situation I asked about. And you didn't answer the question about what exactly an extension package was.

Comment: @fred Read my answer even I highlighted the same thing. i never said you are upgrading from beta to beta. And I mention to remove dependent package first. Thats what you did in the end